# Unable to interpolate sensitive environment variables

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a piece of code that runs like this

```
package core.jenkins

class Utils implements Serializable {
    def script

    Utils(script) {
        this.script = script
    }

    def func() {
        script.withCredentials([script.usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'chartmuseum-basic-auth', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
            script.sh "helm repo add --username script.USER} --password ${script.PASSWORD} chartmuseum \"http://${chartmuseumHostname}:8080\""
        }
}
```

The above works perfectly fine but I do not a warning

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [PASSWORD, USER]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ helm repo add --username **** --password **** chartmuseum http://apps-chartmuseum.apps.svc.cluster.local:8080
```

So following the guide, Im doing the following

```
script.withCredentials([script.usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'chartmuseum-basic-auth', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
script.sh 'helm repo add --username $script.USER --password $script.PASSWORD chartmuseum "http://$chartmuseumHostname:8080"'
        }
```

But running the variable values are not be properly substitured and I get

```
+ helm repo add --username .USER --password .PASSWORD chartmuseum http://:8080
Error: Looks like "http://:8080" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get http://:8080/index.yaml: dial tcp :8080: connect: connection refused
```

So neither the credentials nor the value of the `chartmuseumHostname` variable is being substituted correctly. What am I missing here ?

Comment: You are trying to resolve a shell environment variable with Groovy syntax. You need to try this differently. To assist with the new direction, could you please explain why are you invoking `withCredentials` as a member method of `script` instead of as a function? That would be the easiest path to resolving this issue.

Comment: Because I am writing a shared library for Jenkins and am following the guide https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps

Comment: Ok I would heavily recommend using a global var instead of a shared library for this. It would provide the same advantages you are looking for with this approach, but without the limitations causing you problems. It also fits more naturally since you are doing Pipeline methods and not Java or Groovy within the code.

Answer (score 2):

Actuall withCredentials() creates a environment variable which you can access it from shell scripts.
See here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/
Try using directly the shell variables:

```
script.sh 'helm repo add --username $USER --password $PASSWORD chartmuseum "http://$chartmuseumHostname:8080"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just binding together the answers already on this post, the `withCredentials` makes it so that you should be able to use the variables directly (answer by @catalin), the single quotes make it so that jenkins should stop complaining about security and if you want to be extra careful, you can double quote the variable values as suggested in the docs for `withCredentials`.

This should give you something like this:

```
script.withCredentials([script.usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'chartmuseum-basic-auth', 
                                                usernameVariable: 'USER', 
                                                passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
  script.sh 'helm repo add --username "$USER" --password "$PASSWORD" chartmuseum "http://$chartmuseumHostname:8080"'
}
```

which still leaves us with the question of why you are calling things with the `script.` prefix as mentioned in the comments by @matt-schuchard.

Comment: He calls things with the script object as he probably uses a library to store jenkins pipelines. That's a know limitation and to be able to use jenkins dsl methods in scripted pipeline from a lib, you need to pass 'this' when invoking your lib constructor, script object represents 'this'

Answer (score 0):

I try using the suggestion by @Catalin (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/ using directly the shell variables)
But for me adding double quotes inside single quotes doesn't work.
The only solution I found is taking the variables out of the single quotes like:

> 'myscript $secretvariable' + notsecretvariable

Examples:

Test1: Try using recommended solution (jenkins/@catalin)

Code:

```
sh label: 'Test1', script: 'echo this is a secret $docker_pwd this is not "$dockerRegistry"'
```

Result: variable dockerRegistry is not interpolated/resolved

```
15:50:43  [Pipeline] sh (Test1)
15:50:43  + echo this is a secret **** this is not ''
15:50:43  this is a secret **** this is not
```

Test2: Take non-sensitive variable out of the single quotes:

```
 sh label: 'Test2', script: 'echo this is a secret $docker_pwd this is not' + dockerRegistry
```

Result: variable dockerRegistry is properlly resolved

```
15:50:44  [Pipeline] sh (Test2)
15:50:44  + echo this is a secret **** this is not my.repositories.xx
15:50:44  this is a secret **** this is not my.repositories.xx
```